# How to preserve new lines and formatting while substituting text using sed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a template file like this

```
$ cat template.txt
QWERTY
~SQL~
ASDFG
```

I need to substitute the `"~SQL~"` string in the template file with following text. This text is stored in a variable

```
SELECT COL1,
       COL2,
       COL3
FROM TABLE;
```

I tried the following code, but got an error: **sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command**

```
$ query='SELECT COL1,
>        COL2,
>        COL3
> FROM TABLE;'
$ 
$ sed "s/~SQL~/$query/" template.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command
```

If I remove the new lines from `"query"`, the sed command works fine

```
$ query='SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE;'
$ sed "s/~SQL~/$query/" template.txt
QWERTY
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE;
ASDFG
```

I would like to preserve the new lines and formatting while substituting the text. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v q="$query" '/~SQL~/{$0 = q} 1' file
QWERTY
SELECT COL1,
       COL2,
       COL3,
FROM TABLE;
ASDFG
```

Comment: Great! That works @anubhava. Thanks for the answer :) But what if template.txt has the following lines `QWERT
~SQL~
ASDF`

Comment: Careful with that `sub()` if the query can contain an `&` or =, less likely I suppose, `\<digit>`.

Comment: My requirement is pretty simple, I guess. The template.txt file has multiple lines of text. One of those lines will be `~SQL~`. I need to substitute that line only and other lines should be printed as it is. Sorry for not making this clear in the original question. I have edited the question now.

Comment: ok check my updated answer when `~SQL~` is in a separate line.

Comment: It works @anubhava. Thanks again for helping me. But I could not understand why you have used a "1" at the end of the awk script. What does that "1" do?

Comment: 1 is short cut for print which is default action in awk. It is basically printing each record.

Comment: Yes. Thanks anubhava. I got the meaning of "1" from here - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-awk-script

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
query='SELECT COL1,\n       COL2,\n       COL3\nFROM TABLE;'
sed "s/~SQL~/$query/" template.txt
```